# Tranformation of random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, transformation

Let $X$ have the p.d.f $f(x)= e^{-x}$, $ x > 0$, $0 $  otherwise,find the pdf of $Y = X^2$ and space range $Y$.

I use the change of variable formula

The inverse is

$${x} = \sqrt{{y}} $$

The derivative is
$$f(x)= \frac{1}  {2\sqrt{y}}$$

The pdf is 
$$ \frac{e^{-\sqrt{{y}}}}  {2\sqrt{y}}$$

My question is how do I get the range? and how do I check that I am correct? I saw that I can use integration, but what limits should I use?

Comment: Hint: $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\sqrt{y}}}{2\sqrt{y}}$ = 1. As for the range if $x>0$ then what is $x^2$?

Comment: Your density function is correct, except you should have specified that is given by your formula for $y\gt 0$, and is $0$ for $y\le 0$. There could be arguments about the range, $(0,\infty) or $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: If I use substitution as you told me the range is 1, 4, 9,..., , why I have to use 0 in the limits of integration?

Comment: The range of $x$ is not over integers. It is over all real numbers. If $x>0$ then $x^2>0$ which means that the range of $y$ is 0 to infinity. The hint I gave above is a way to check your answer. If you like you can think of 0 as $0^+$, which means arbitrarily close to zero over all positive reals.

Comment: Let me know if you still don't understand.

Comment: I am not understanding the range part if 0 is not included in x, how can it be included in y?, is there any way to check that?

Comment: The range of $x$ includes $1/2$ it also includes $1/4$, it also includes $1/8$. It includes any number of the form $1/2^n$ for all $n$. Since $1/2^n$ tends to zero from the right (i.e. over all positive number, no matter how small), the range of $x$ includes $0$ from the right. The notation for that is $0^+$, or simply 0, with the right understood from the context.

Comment: I looked again, they said $x\gt 0$ for $X$, so it is the same for $Y$.

Comment: Yes. Since $x>0$, you conclude that $x^2>0$ and hence $y>0$, which means that $y$ includes $0^+$.

Comment: so from 0 to infinity I have to integrate, I think I understand now, one more question in what ways can not be 0 to infinity?

Comment: Oh I see it now thank you @mhp

Comment: thanks also to @AndréNicolas